# Avoiding reentry into positions of the same direction

Tags: pine-script

Hello I am new to pine script and I am testing a strategy that has different entry conditions and exit conditions. The problem I am having is when an exit occurs, the entry conditions could still be met and is reentering into the same position as before. I never want to enter the same direction position, ie if I close a long I do not want to reenter a long again until I have encountered a short. Is there any way to ask the script to check if the last entered position was a long, to not enter into a long again unless a short has occurred first?

Answer (score 0):

When your entry conditions are met and supplied to the strategy.entry() function, additionally set a persistent variable.
For example:

```
var bool lastTradeLong = na
long = crossover(a,b)
long_entry = long and (na(lastTradeLong) or not lastTradeLong)
if long_entry
    lastTradeLong := true
strategy.entry('Long', strategy.long, when=long_entry)
```

And set the reverse for short, so enter when your short conditions are true, and `lastTradeLong` is either `na` or `true`, and then when that combination happens and the trade enters, set lastTradeLong to false.